# Sharepoint 2013 Online filter by attachments name

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, wcf, attachments

i want to query to list items by filtering attachments name with default WCF query. But i get an error. My query is below. Is that possible?

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/<MyListTitle>?$expand=Attachments&$filter=substringof('foo',Attachments/Name)
```

Error says

> No property 'Name' exists in type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataServiceEntity, Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c]]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported to apply `$filter` query option to `Attachments` field type, it is a similar restriction as for *multi-value lookup fields and users*.

According to [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385(v=office.15).aspx):

> **Queries for multi-value lookup fields and users** Because multi-value
>   lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple values, there is no
>   way to query for them (for example, the equivalent of an Includes
>   element or NotIncludes element is not supported).

As a workaround, you could consider to apply filtering to the returned results:

```
var endpointUrl = 'https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Tasks?$expand=Attachments';
var findText = 'Office 365';

$.getJSON(endpointUrl, function(data) {
   var items  = data.d.results;
   var filteredItems = items.filter(function(item){
       var foundAttachments = item.Attachments.results.filter(function(attachment){
           if(attachment.Name.indexOf(findText) > -1)
               return attachment;
       });
       if(foundAttachments.length > 0)
           return item;
   });

   //print filtered results 
   filteredItems.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item.TaskName); 
   });


});
```

Comment: Thanks but i am working on something like search on a list and i am looking for specific text for specific column for example Content column also i want to search for attachment name. Is there best practice for this? Maybe i can do store attachments names in another column and search for new column example AttachmentsNames?

Comment: Creating a separate text column for storing attachment names sounds good. But remember you need to keep it sync with Attachments field

Comment: Users adding new item in custom webpart programmatically so i can manage sync issue i think. Thanks for your care.