# OData Query Options for SPO List Attachments

Tags: sharepoint-online, odata

I am using SSIS with an OData source to pull SharePoint Online 2013 List data into a SQL table. I'd like to filter on the `Attachments` boolean but can not figure out how to query it.

I saw that an `Attachments` property exists when I export the Attachment xml information from `/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('<List>')/items?$expand=AttachmentFiles`. I see the following:

```
        <m:properties>
            <d:FileSystemObjectType m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:FileSystemObjectType>
            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">143</d:Id>
            <d:ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl/>
            <d:ContentTypeId>0x010029B7BBCFD15FFC439AC3ED59CAD79F26</d:ContentTypeId>
            <d:Title m:null="true"/>
            <d:OData__x0031_0BDays_Email_Date m:null="true"/>
            <d:OData__x0032_0BDays_Email_Date m:null="true"/>
            <d:OData__x0033_BDays_Email_Date m:null="true"/>
            <d:Covenant_Owner_Name m:null="true"/>
            <d:Covenant_Owner_Id m:null="true"/>
            <d:Frequency_Narration m:null="true"/>
            <d:Business_OwnerId m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Business_OwnerId>
            <d:Executive_OwnerId m:type="Edm.Int32">37</d:Executive_OwnerId>
            <d:AuthorId m:type="Edm.Int32">491</d:AuthorId>
            <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32">248</d:EditorId>
            <d:Modified m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-05-10T13:24:58Z</d:Modified>
            <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-05-04T13:40:05Z</d:Created>
            <d:Flexible m:null="true"/>
            <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32">143</d:ID>
            <d:OData__UIVersionString>2.0</d:OData__UIVersionString>
            <d:Attachments m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:Attachments>
            <d:GUID m:type="Edm.Guid">6e808ac8-b836-49b0-8343-9ae627b661d0</d:GUID>
        </m:properties>
```

I assume since I can query on an OData source with query options like `$filter` and `$select` that I could filter for:
`$filter = Attachments eq true` as a query option since many of the other parameters do work, like `Id`, `AuthorId`, etc.

[image]

The error I receive is pretty vague:
`The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` and the following when I expand it:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (System)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.Http.HttpWebRequestWrapper.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.Http.WebRequestHelper.GetResponseWithThreadSafeRetry(IWebRequest& request, Func`1 createWebRequest, Int32 retryCount, Int32 retrySleepInMilliseconds, Boolean isOAuth, Func`2 refreshRequestWithNewAccessToken, Func`2 getStatusCode)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.Http.WebRequestHelper.GetResponseWithThreadSafeRetryAndImpersonation(IWebRequest& request, DataFeedConnection connection, Func`1 createWebRequest)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.DataFeedClient.DataFeedCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DataFlowUI.ODataConnectionPage.PreviewButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering

`$filter=Attachments eq true`

try

`$filter=Attachments ne false`.

Works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Using `ne false` gave me the same error as before. I stumbled across [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143830/sharepoint-2013-online-filter-by-attachments-name) question that states you can't filter on attachments. I'm hoping it's not entirely true though. Any thoughts?